# incorrect position when draw image context into UIImage that has been scale to another size;

Tags: iphone, uiimage, transform, cgcontext

my uiimage has been add to UIView, then i transform it to scale 1.5

when i try to draw image context it will present incorrect position

how to make ImageContext in transform size ?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the image at the origin. Scale it however much you want. Then translate to where you want the image to be.

Comment: you mean all imagecontext use the old algorithm and insert to UIImage after that transform to specific scale?

Comment: Draw UIImage to UIView at origin (0,0). Use transform to scale contents of UIView to new size. Use transform to move contents of UIView to new location.